Is there an API for sending messages to users on behalf of the company?
I would like to know if there is a request behind the API to respond to a message to a user on behalf of a company and what this request should look like. I didn't find a specific request in the Linkedin API documentation and I'm wondering if such an option is even provided for developers?
I tried to find the answer in the documentation, but either I'm blind or there's no answer there :(
